# I change my admin password but nothing happens

Tags: php

this page is about connection and fetching the detail from database, useraccounts is the database name,and users is the table name

```
 session_start();

    $_SESSION["userId"] = "1";
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "useraccounts") or die("Connection Error: " . mysqli_error($conn));

    if (count($_POST) > 0) {
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT *from useraccounts WHERE userId='" . $_SESSION["userId"] . "'");

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        if ($_POST["currentPassword"] == $row["password"]) {
            mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users set password='" . $_POST["newPassword"] . "' WHERE userId='" . $_SESSION["userId"] . "'");
            $message = "Password Changed";
        } else
            $message = "Current Password is not correct";
    ?>
```

Comment: Add provide more details on the error. And please format your code.

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to SQL Injections. Consider using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: `SELECT *from useraccounts` but updating `users`. Understand what you do in your code "as much as soon".

Comment: This piece of code `if ($_POST["currentPassword"] == $row["password"])` could be the issue. Are the passwords plain text saved ?

Comment: nothing happens when i submit the detail..

Comment: when i click on submit button it shows nothin even error..

Comment: Show the code for the form

Comment: thanks i did it today

Comment: if you want to ask about something please give more detail problem and what do you want.. thx